# Parse.com – Regularly refill energy

Tags: parse-platform

The User class has an Energy column, a number that caps at 30. Every 10 minutes, every User object should regenerate 1 energy. What's the best way to achieve this functionality?

As a bonus, is there a way to make each User have its own unique timer, so that it starts counting down 10 minutes as soon as he uses his first energy after it's been capped?

Currently interested in using Parse.com, and I'm assuming Cloud Code needs to be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a good reason for it, don't try to put game logic in your database. Especially don't try to architect a solution where you have to run thousands of timers on your server.

Timer code belongs in the client.

The way I would implement it is to store the last date/time they got energy and when a timer fires in the app compare "now" to that and add as much energy as needed, storing the new date/time of the most recent 10 minute boundary.

This logic would also handle the app being asleep/closed during that time, simply call the same code on app start.

If security is an issue then store the data to calculate this securely and put this logic in a cloud function, but still have the timer that calls it in the client.

How frequently you fire the timer using this method is up to you. You could fire it every second if you really wanted to and it would still only add energy every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, Timothy! I actually came to this conclusion yesterday as well, and wrote up some pseudocode to get me started. Thanks again for all your great advice!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Code can help if you write a Job that you can run every 10 minutes, but there are limited to what you can do. Firstly, the Job can only take a maximum of 4 seconds to execute, which means it won't be possible to update a large list of Users using Cloud Code.

The best solution would be to write a script that you can call on your server every 10 minutes, e.g. a cronjob.

Using Parse, you can check a timestamp in the Class and retrieve any users that need their Energy updated. The script would then cycle through that list and update their Energy by 1. Schedule the script to run every minute, so that Energy is updated to the nearest minute after use.

Comment: There is nothing that is limited to 4 seconds. Job = 15 mins. Function = 15 secs. Trigger (e.g. beforeSave) = 3 secs. https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource

Comment: I stand corrected on the execution times. It still advise to create a script to do the update.